# How to make Jackson throw exception as is when deserialization mapping fail

Tags: java, json, jackson, deserialization

[Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) has a weird behavior in handling Exceptions that occur during deserialization mapping: it throws a `JsonMappingException` whose `.getCause()` returns the innermost of the exception chain.

```
//in main
ObjectMapper jsonMapper = new ObjectMapper();
String json = "{\"id\": 1}";
try {
    Q q = jsonMapper.readValue(json, Q.class);
} catch (JsonMappingException e) {
    System.out.println(e.getCause()); //java.lang.RuntimeException: ex 2
}

//class Q
public class Q {
    @JsonCreator
    public Q(@JsonProperty("id") int id) {
        throw new RuntimeException("ex 0", 
            new RuntimeException("ex 1", 
                new RuntimeException("ex 2")));
    }
}
```

In the code above, I use `jsonMapper.readValue(..)` to map the String `json` to an instance of class `Q` whose the constructor, marked `@JsonCreator`, throws a chain of `RuntimeException`: `"ex 0", "ex 1", "ex 2"`. When the mapping fail, I expected the line `System.out.println(e.getCause());` to print out `ex 0`, but it prints `ex 2`.

Why Jackson decides to do this and is there a way to configure it so that it doesn't discard my `ex 0`? I have tried

```
jsonMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.WRAP_EXCEPTIONS, false);
```

but it doesn't do anything.

Comment: If you are using springboot 1.5 and above, simply adding `spring.jackson.deserialization.wrap-exceptions=false` to your application.properties file will do.

Comment: @Teja, **Please i still stuck against this issue**, _can you have a look at_ [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58525409/how-to-unwrap-custom-runtimeexception-from-json-mapping-exception)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Inside of Jackson's `StdValueInstantiator` this method gets hit when an exception is thrown during deserialization:

```
protected JsonMappingException wrapException(Throwable t)
{
    while (t.getCause() != null) {
        t = t.getCause();
    }
    if (t instanceof JsonMappingException) {
        return (JsonMappingException) t;
    }
    return new JsonMappingException("Instantiation of "+getValueTypeDesc()+" value failed: "+t.getMessage(), t);
}
```

As you can see, this will iterate through each "level" of your nested runtime exceptions and set the last one it hits as the cause for the `JsonMappingException` it returns.

Here is the code I needed to get this working:

1. Register a new module to the `ObjectMapper`.

   ```
   @Test
   public void testJackson() {
       ObjectMapper jsonMapper = new ObjectMapper();
       jsonMapper.registerModule(new MyModule(jsonMapper.getDeserializationConfig()));
       String json = "{\"id\": \"1\"}";
       try {
           Q q = jsonMapper.readValue(json, Q.class);
           System.out.println(q.getId());
       } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
           System.out.println(e.getCause()); //java.lang.RuntimeException: ex 2
       } catch (JsonParseException e) {
       } catch (IOException e) {
       }
   }
   ```
2. Create a custom module class.

   ```
   public class MyModule extends SimpleModule {
       public MyModule(DeserializationConfig deserializationConfig) {
           super("MyModule", ModuleVersion.instance.version());
           addValueInstantiator(Q.class, new MyValueInstantiator(deserializationConfig, Q.class));
           addDeserializer(Q.class, new CustomDeserializer());
       }
   }
   ```
3. Create a custom `ValueInstantiator` class to override `wrapException(...)`. Add the instantiator to the module.

   ```
   public class MyValueInstantiator extends StdValueInstantiator {
       public MyValueInstantiator(DeserializationConfig config, Class<?> valueType) {
           super(config, valueType);
       }

       @Override
       protected JsonMappingException wrapException(Throwable t) {
           if (t instanceof JsonMappingException) {
               return (JsonMappingException) t;
           }
           return new JsonMappingException("Instantiation of "+getValueTypeDesc()+" value failed: "+t.getMessage(), t);
       }
   }
   ```
4. Create a custom deserializer to get the module to work properly. Add this class to the module initialization as well.

   ```
   public class CustomDeserializer extends StdScalarDeserializer<Q> {
       public CustomDeserializer() {
           super(Q.class);
       }

       @Override
       public Q deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext context) throws IOException {
           JsonNode node = jp.getCodec().readTree(jp);
           return new Q(node.get("id").asText());
       }

       @Override
       public Object deserializeWithType(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt, TypeDeserializer typeDeserializer) throws IOException {
           return deserialize(jp, ctxt);
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 2):

For anyone looking for a different solution, this worked for me on Spring Boot 2.2.8.RELEASE. NB: This is example is when you have a rest controller with request body that is has an enum and clients could send a wrong field string gender and you want to provide proper error message:

```
@PostMapping
public ResponseEntity<ProfileResponse> updateProfile(@RequestBody @Valid ProfileRequest profileRequest) {
    
    ProfileResponse profile = //do something important here that returns profile object response
    return ResponseEntity
            .status(HttpStatus.OK)
            .body(profile);
}
```

ProfileRequest looks like

```
@Data //Lombok getters and setters
public class ProfileRequest{
    private GenderEnum gender;
    //some more attributes
}
```

Add this property to the aplication.properties file to make sure that our custom exception GlobalRuntimeException (see later for definition) is not wrapped in JsonMappingException exception.

```
spring.jackson.deserialization.WRAP_EXCEPTIONS=false
```

Then create a class which spring boot will auto create a bean for (This will be used for Deserializing the field gender of type enum). If we don't find an the enum, then we know to throw an error.

```
@JsonComponent
public class GenderEnumDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<GenderEnum> {

    @Override
    public GenderEnum deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {
        String val = p.getValueAsString();
        GenderEnum genderEnum = GenderEnum.fromName(val);
        if(genderEnum == null){
            throw new GlobalRuntimeException("Invalid gender provided. Valid values are MALE | FEMALE | OTHER");
        }
        return genderEnum;
    }

}
```

The "forName" method in GenderEnum looks like below.

```
public static GenderEnum fromName(String name) {
    GenderEnum foundGenderEnum = null;
    for (GenderEnum genderEnum : values()) {
        if (genderEnum.name().equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {
            foundGenderEnum = genderEnum;
        }
    }
    return foundGenderEnum;
}
```

We would then setup catching the GlobalRuntimeException in our ControllerAdvice:

```
@ResponseBody
@ExceptionHandler(GlobalRuntimeException.class)
ResponseEntity<?> handleInvalidGlobalRuntimeException(HttpServletRequest request, GlobalRuntimeException ex) {
    LOGGER.error("Error " + ex);
    return ResponseEntity
            .status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
            .body(new ErrorMessage(ex.getCustomMessage));
}
```

That's it.

Comment: The property `spring.jackson.deserialization.WRAP_EXCEPTIONS=false` is exactly what I needed! Adding this property allowed my exceptions which I was throwing from my custom deseralizer to be handled correctly by my ControllerAdvice without it being wrapped in the JsonMappingException.