# How to catch customize exeception in Date JsonDeserializer?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, date, json-deserialization

Implementaion: Im trying to show the customize exception `DATE_FORMAT_EXCEPTION` with a message of `Date format is wrong` if error. But even i input a wrong format the customize exception wont show but there is error `400 Bad Request` and i use `Exception` which catch all the error.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.time.LocalDate;

import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Date;


import com.cartgatewayservice.RestModelException.DATE_FORMAT_EXCEPTION;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JacksonException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonDeserializer;

public class DateDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Date> {

    @Override
    public Date deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JacksonException {
        
        DateTimeFormatter localDateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
        
        String dateValue = p.getValueAsString();
        

        try {
            
              LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse(dateValue, localDateFormatter);
              return convertToDateViaInstant(localDate);
          
        } catch (Exception e) {
              throw new DATE_FORMAT_EXCEPTION("Date format is wrong");
        }
    
    }
    
      public Date convertToDateViaInstant(LocalDate dateToConvert) {
            return Date.from(dateToConvert.atStartOfDay()
                    .atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())
                    .toInstant());
        }
    


}
```

```
import java.util.Date;

import com.cartgatewayservice.BodyConvertParameters.DateDeserializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.OptBoolean;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonDeserialize;

import org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.ToString;


@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString
@Builder
public class ProductEntity {
    

  
    
    @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE)
    @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd", shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, lenient = OptBoolean.FALSE)
   @JsonDeserialize(using = DateDeserializer.class)
    private Date productexpirationdate;

}
```

```
public class DATE_FORMAT_EXCEPTION extends RuntimeException  {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    public DATE_FORMAT_EXCEPTION(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}
```

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class RestAdviceException extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {


    @ExceptionHandler(DATE_FORMAT_EXCEPTION.class)
    public ResponseEntity<Object>  handleFormatDateEntity(DATE_FORMAT_EXCEPTION ex, WebRequest request) {
        return new ResponseEntity<Object>(new ERROR_DETAILS_EXCEPTION(ex.getMessage(), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, LocalDateTime.now()),HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        
    ..........
    }

}
```

Comment: You should show your `DATE_FORMAT_EXCEPTION` class, and note that `Exception` is only a subset of `Throwable` (which _would_ describe anything that could be thrown, including errors). Lastly, note that `Throwable` objects accept another `Throwable` in their constructor, which would allow for "nested exceptions". These would print the first exception (the "wrapper"), followed by a "Caused by: " line (the "wrapped" exception).

Comment: @Rogue `DATE_FORMAT_EXCEPTION class` i added the class. Thanks for guide

Comment: fix https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58525409/how-to-unwrap-custom-runtimeexception-from-json-mapping-exception the last part about @ControllerAdvice